# Recovering Data from eMMC Chip

Tags: data-recovery

Some months ago, my sweetie's phone died -- an HTC One M7 -- and a well-rated local phone tech was unable to resurrect it.  She dearly wanted to get as much data back out of the phone as possible, but as it wasn't switching on, much less enumerating over USB, ordinary data recovery techniques were not possible.

With conventional solutions seemingly exhausted, I decided to get unconventional.  As the phone was already effectively and unrecoverably bricked, I got a very skilled friend to disassemble the phone and remove the eMMC chip from the board.  I purchased an eMMC pogo pin reader, placed the chip in it, and attempted to read it on my Linux PC.

To my surprise, the chip appeared to be recognized by the OS and appeared in /dev with the nodes `/dev/mmcblk0`, `/dev/mmcblk0boot0`, and `/dev/mmcblk0boot1`, which was expected.  However, the OS reported no partitions, and dumping all the block devices returned nothing but a sea of zeros.

It's this last part that has me confused.  The "natural" state of a flash cell is a logical high (0xFFFF....), and is what I would expect to see if the chip had been damaged during removal or the pogo pins weren't making proper contact.  But here I'm seeing all zeros.  It seems inconceivable to me that the entire chip could have been filled with zeros by any normal operation, or even a rogue program running with root privileges on the phone.

My Question:  Am I seeing the chip's true current state, or have I mucked something up in trying to hook it up and talk to it?  Is there anything else that can be tried, or am I at the end-game?

Here are some diagnostics from sysfs and from Linux's `mmc` tool.  The eMMC chip in question is (I'm pretty sure) a Hynix H26M64002DQR:

```
$ cd /sys/bus/mmc/devices/mmc0:0001
$ ls -F
block/   dsr                   fwrev   oemid                 rel_sectors
cid      enhanced_area_offset  hwrev   power/                serial
csd      enhanced_area_size    manfid  preferred_erase_size  subsystem@
date     erase_size            name    prv                   type
driver@  ffu_capable           ocr     raw_rpmb_size_mult    uevent
$ cat cid
90014a484247346504010947a6b83001
$ cat csd
d02701320f5903ffffffffef8a404001
$ cat date
03/2013
$ cat dsr
0x404
$ cat enhanced_area_offset 
18446744073709551594
$ cat enhanced_area_size 
4294967274
$ cat erase_size 
524288
$ cat fwrev 
0x0
$ cat hwrev 
0x0
$ cat manfid 
0x000090
$ cat name 
HBG4e
$ cat ocr
00000080
$ cat oemid 
0x014a
$ cat prv
0x1
$ cat rel_sectors 
0x1
$ cat type 
MMC
$ sudo mmc status get /dev/mmcblk0
SEND_STATUS response: 0x00000900
$ sudo mmc extcsd read /dev/mmcblk0
=============================================
  Extended CSD rev 1.6 (MMC 4.5)
=============================================

Card Supported Command sets [S_CMD_SET: 0x01]
HPI Features [HPI_FEATURE: 0x03]: implementation based on CMD12
Background operations support [BKOPS_SUPPORT: 0x01]
Max Packet Read Cmd [MAX_PACKED_READS: 0x08]
Max Packet Write Cmd [MAX_PACKED_WRITES: 0x08]
Data TAG support [DATA_TAG_SUPPORT: 0x01]
Data TAG Unit Size [TAG_UNIT_SIZE: 0x00]
Tag Resources Size [TAG_RES_SIZE: 0x06]
Context Management Capabilities [CONTEXT_CAPABILITIES: 0x78]
Large Unit Size [LARGE_UNIT_SIZE_M1: 0x01]
Extended partition attribute support [EXT_SUPPORT: 0x03]
Generic CMD6 Timer [GENERIC_CMD6_TIME: 0x64]
Power off notification [POWER_OFF_LONG_TIME: 0x64]
Cache Size [CACHE_SIZE] is 512 KiB
Background operations status [BKOPS_STATUS: 0x00]
1st Initialisation Time after programmed sector [INI_TIMEOUT_AP: 0x0a]
Power class for 52MHz, DDR at 3.6V [PWR_CL_DDR_52_360: 0x00]
Power class for 52MHz, DDR at 1.95V [PWR_CL_DDR_52_195: 0x00]
Power class for 200MHz at 3.6V [PWR_CL_200_360: 0x00]
Power class for 200MHz, at 1.95V [PWR_CL_200_195: 0x00]
Minimum Performance for 8bit at 52MHz in DDR mode:
 [MIN_PERF_DDR_W_8_52: 0x00]
 [MIN_PERF_DDR_R_8_52: 0x00]
TRIM Multiplier [TRIM_MULT: 0x01]
Secure Feature support [SEC_FEATURE_SUPPORT: 0x55]
Boot Information [BOOT_INFO: 0x07]
 Device supports alternative boot method
 Device supports dual data rate during boot
 Device supports high speed timing during boot
Boot partition size [BOOT_SIZE_MULTI: 0x20]
Access size [ACC_SIZE: 0x06]
High-capacity erase unit size [HC_ERASE_GRP_SIZE: 0x01]
 i.e. 512 KiB
High-capacity erase timeout [ERASE_TIMEOUT_MULT: 0x02]
Reliable write sector count [REL_WR_SEC_C: 0x01]
High-capacity W protect group size [HC_WP_GRP_SIZE: 0x10]
 i.e. 8192 KiB
Sleep current (VCC) [S_C_VCC: 0x07]
Sleep current (VCCQ) [S_C_VCCQ: 0x07]
Sleep/awake timeout [S_A_TIMEOUT: 0x13]
Sector Count [SEC_COUNT: 0x03a40000]
 Device is block-addressed
Minimum Write Performance for 8bit:
 [MIN_PERF_W_8_52: 0x08]
 [MIN_PERF_R_8_52: 0x08]
 [MIN_PERF_W_8_26_4_52: 0x08]
 [MIN_PERF_R_8_26_4_52: 0x08]
Minimum Write Performance for 4bit:
 [MIN_PERF_W_4_26: 0x08]
 [MIN_PERF_R_4_26: 0x08]
Power classes registers:
 [PWR_CL_26_360: 0x00]
 [PWR_CL_52_360: 0x00]
 [PWR_CL_26_195: 0x00]
 [PWR_CL_52_195: 0x00]
Partition switching timing [PARTITION_SWITCH_TIME: 0x03]
Out-of-interrupt busy timing [OUT_OF_INTERRUPT_TIME: 0x02]
I/O Driver Strength [DRIVER_STRENGTH: 0x01]
Card Type [CARD_TYPE: 0x17]
 HS200 Single Data Rate eMMC @200MHz 1.8VI/O
 HS Dual Data Rate eMMC @52MHz 1.8V or 3VI/O
 HS eMMC @52MHz - at rated device voltage(s)
 HS eMMC @26MHz - at rated device voltage(s)
CSD structure version [CSD_STRUCTURE: 0x02]
Command set [CMD_SET: 0x00]
Command set revision [CMD_SET_REV: 0x00]
Power class [POWER_CLASS: 0x00]
High-speed interface timing [HS_TIMING: 0x01]
Erased memory content [ERASED_MEM_CONT: 0x00]
Boot configuration bytes [PARTITION_CONFIG: 0x00]
 Not boot enable
 No access to boot partition
Boot config protection [BOOT_CONFIG_PROT: 0x00]
Boot bus Conditions [BOOT_BUS_CONDITIONS: 0x00]
High-density erase group definition [ERASE_GROUP_DEF: 0x00]
Boot write protection status registers [BOOT_WP_STATUS]: 0x00
Boot Area Write protection [BOOT_WP]: 0x00
 Power ro locking: possible
 Permanent ro locking: possible
 ro lock status: not locked
User area write protection register [USER_WP]: 0x00
FW configuration [FW_CONFIG]: 0x00
RPMB Size [RPMB_SIZE_MULT]: 0x20
Write reliability setting register [WR_REL_SET]: 0x1f
 user area: the device protects existing data if a power failure occurs during a write operation
 partition 1: the device protects existing data if a power failure occurs during a write operation
 partition 2: the device protects existing data if a power failure occurs during a write operation
 partition 3: the device protects existing data if a power failure occurs during a write operation
 partition 4: the device protects existing data if a power failure occurs during a write operation
Write reliability parameter register [WR_REL_PARAM]: 0x05
 Device supports writing EXT_CSD_WR_REL_SET
 Device supports the enhanced def. of reliable write
Enable background operations handshake [BKOPS_EN]: 0x01
H/W reset function [RST_N_FUNCTION]: 0x01
HPI management [HPI_MGMT]: 0x01
Partitioning Support [PARTITIONING_SUPPORT]: 0x07
 Device support partitioning feature
 Device can have enhanced tech.
Max Enhanced Area Size [MAX_ENH_SIZE_MULT]: 0x000748
 i.e. 15269888 KiB
Partitions attribute [PARTITIONS_ATTRIBUTE]: 0x00
Partitioning Setting [PARTITION_SETTING_COMPLETED]: 0x00
 Device partition setting NOT complete
General Purpose Partition Size
 [GP_SIZE_MULT_4]: 0x000000
 [GP_SIZE_MULT_3]: 0x000000
 [GP_SIZE_MULT_2]: 0x000000
 [GP_SIZE_MULT_1]: 0x000000
Enhanced User Data Area Size [ENH_SIZE_MULT]: 0x000000
 i.e. 0 KiB
Enhanced User Data Start Address [ENH_START_ADDR]: 0x000000
 i.e. 0 bytes offset
Bad Block Management mode [SEC_BAD_BLK_MGMNT]: 0x00
Periodic Wake-up [PERIODIC_WAKEUP]: 0x00
Program CID/CSD in DDR mode support [PROGRAM_CID_CSD_DDR_SUPPORT]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[127]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[126]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[125]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[124]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[123]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[122]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[121]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[120]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[119]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[118]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[117]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[116]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[115]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[114]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[113]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[112]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[111]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[110]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[109]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[108]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[107]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[106]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[105]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[104]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[103]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[102]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[101]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[100]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[99]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[98]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[97]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[96]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[95]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[94]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[93]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[92]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[91]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[90]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[89]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[88]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[87]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[86]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[85]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[84]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[83]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[82]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[81]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[80]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[79]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[78]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[77]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[76]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[75]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[74]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[73]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[72]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[71]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[70]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[69]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[68]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[67]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[66]]: 0x37
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[65]]: 0xff
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[64]]: 0xff
Native sector size [NATIVE_SECTOR_SIZE]: 0x01
Sector size emulation [USE_NATIVE_SECTOR]: 0x00
Sector size [DATA_SECTOR_SIZE]: 0x00
1st initialization after disabling sector size emulation [INI_TIMEOUT_EMU]: 0x0a
Class 6 commands control [CLASS_6_CTRL]: 0x00
Number of addressed group to be Released[DYNCAP_NEEDED]: 0x00
Exception events control [EXCEPTION_EVENTS_CTRL]: 0x0000
Exception events status[EXCEPTION_EVENTS_STATUS]: 0x0000
Extended Partitions Attribute [EXT_PARTITIONS_ATTRIBUTE]: 0x0000
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[51]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[50]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[49]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[48]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[47]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[46]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[45]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[44]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[43]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[42]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[41]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[40]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[39]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[38]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[37]]: 0x00
Packed command status [PACKED_COMMAND_STATUS]: 0x00
Packed command failure index [PACKED_FAILURE_INDEX]: 0x00
Power Off Notification [POWER_OFF_NOTIFICATION]: 0x01
Control to turn the Cache ON/OFF [CACHE_CTRL]: 0x01
```

#### Additional Requested Info

`fdisk` output:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 29.1 GiB, 31272730624 bytes, 61079552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0boot0
Disk /dev/mmcblk0boot0: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0boot1
Disk /dev/mmcblk0boot1: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: Perhaps [electronics.se] would be a better place for this given the technical nature of your question?

Comment: I actually considered posting there, but was concerned that, since the question centered around data recovery and not strictly EE, it wasn't appropriate there.  However, if wiser minds choose to migrate it there, I won't complain.

Comment: Mmcblk0boot0,1 would seem to be partitions. When you say "the os didnt recognise" do you mean "it didnt automount"?

Results of `fdisk -l`, `dd if=mmcblk0 of=~/home/$USER/Desktop/mmcimg.iso && mount -o loop mmcimg.iso /mnt`

Comment: Uh, no.  If all you've ever dealt with are HDDs and SSDs, eMMC devices can seem a bit goofy.  In addition to the "main" block storage area (`mmcblk0`), eMMC devices also have additional storage areas -- typically two areas intended for holding boot code (`mmcblk0boot0`, `mmcblk0boot1`), and an optional RPMB (Replay-Protected Memory Block, not enabled on this chip).  Each is logically distinct and appears as a separate device.  In my case, all three of those areas contain nothing but zeros, i.e. no partition tables.

Answer (score 2):

First... I know just enough to get me in trouble and little else.

the emmc is comprised of several partitions within.  you will need to derive each mmcblock within the mmcblock0.

I know for use while in working phone you would use the following command in adb shell

```
cat /proc/emmc
```

Should list all mount points on disk similar to the following

mmcblk0p22: 000ffa00 00000200 "misc"
mmcblk0p21: 00fffe00 00000200 "recovery"
mmcblk0p20: 01000000 00000200 "boot"
mmcblk0p33: 54fffc00 00000200 "system"
mmcblk0p29: 00140200 00000200 "local"
mmcblk0p34: 0dfffe00 00000200 "cache"
mmcblk0p35: 49fffe00 00000200 "userdata"
mmcblk0p25: 01400000 00000200 "devlog"
mmcblk0p27: 00040000 00000200 "pdata"
mmcblk0p36: 1097fe000 00000200 "fat"
mmcblk0p30: 00010000 00000200 "extra"
mmcblk0p16: 02d00000 00000200 "radio"
mmcblk0p17: 00a00000 00000200 "adsp"
mmcblk0p15: 00100000 00000200 "dsps"
mmcblk0p18: 00500000 00000200 "wcnss"
mmcblk0p19: 007ffa00 00000200 "radio_config"
mmcblk0p23: 00400000 00000200 "modem_st1"
mmcblk0p24: 00400000 00000200 "modem_st2"
mmcblk0p31: 00100000 00000200 "cdma_record"

The syntax to gather the info will likely differ with chip mounted in pogo.  I imagine the concept should be the same

Then us dd if of statement to extract needed partitions
(knowing little about available formats to extract to and full capable function of dd; what I read suggested *.img;...  then more work needed to decompile them getting the actual directory structure inside them.)

```
dd if=/dev/mmcblk* of=/(path to save)/blk*.img
```

again the syntax in your scenario will/may differ

the .img files are not images of a partition, but of a whole disk. That means they start with a bootloader and a partition table. You have to find out the offset of the partition and mount it with the offset option of mount
find offset:

```
 fdisk -l /path/to/image
```

it will show you the block-size and the start-block of the partition. You can use that to calculate the offset.

Once calcutated:

basic syntax

```
mount -o loop,offset=(calc here) Stick.img /mnt/tmp
```

sources:
[Partition lists](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/92565/how-to-list-all-major-partitions-with-their-labels)
[Make Image](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509639/making-full-disk-image-with-dd)
[Mount img](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-to-mount-img-file-882386/)

Edit per request

The sources are weak at best and not completely viable.  Google is your friend.

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...